# Why is New Hampshire more conservative than Vermont?

Tags: united-states, election, demographics

Why is Vermont more liberal than New Hampshire. Vermont hasn't had a republican elector since 1988, while New Hampshire did in 2000.

Moreover, in 2016 New Hampshire is going/went to Clinton by a mere percent, while Vermont went by close to 30.

They seem to have the same culture and neighborhood.

Comment: They don't.  Vermont's culture is fairly... unique.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why has Vermont been so reliably blue since 1992, despite being so white and rural?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/14122/why-has-vermont-been-so-reliably-blue-since-1992-despite-being-so-white-and-rur/19230#19230)

Comment: @lazarusL That question is very similar to this one, but not exactly the same.  That question has no mention of New Hampshire.  This is more a comparison of two very similar states geographically and demographically, yet are so different politically.

Answer (score 4):

According to this article, there were multiple factors involved but the conclusion appears to be that the deciding factor was migration:

[Vermont and New Hampshire, Geographic twins, Cultural aliens](https://news.harvard.edu/gazette/story/2007/11/vermont-and-new-hampshire-geographic-twins-cultural-aliens/)

Here is a very intriguing intro, which leads one to believe what @bike says.

> There is no simple answer, but, he said, there were many wrong turns in a search for illuminating data, which had to span at least 50 to 100 years.
>
> Can demographics explain why the two states diverged? Nope. A century of census data on Vermont and New Hampshire shows that both states remain “extremely white” and largely Christian, said Kaufman.
>
> How about economics? Another false lead, Kaufman said. Vermont is somewhat more agricultural, though not enough so to explain the cultural divergence. And both states have a small manufacturing base.
>
> Educational profile? “Really no difference,” he said.

Here is the article's conclusion.

> In sum, Vermont engineered a new brand for itself — a hybrid culture of the old and the new. New Hampshire held on to a brand that was a variation of the old one.
>
> All this took “an unintentional concatenation of forces,” said Kaufman. “[But] Matt and I think the migration factor is the key.”